# Get ID of model inside eloquent query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Is there any way to get the ID inside the query?

I don't know how to explain this fluently, but I'm trying to grab the product options for each product, but i need to use the product ID inside the with statement to do that.

Something like that but `$idOfModel` should obviously be the id of each product.

```
$products = Product::with('attributes', function($q) {
            $q->with('product_options', function($q) {
                $q->where('product_id', $idOfModel)->with('variable', function($q) {
                    $q->where('product_id', $idOfModel);
                });
            })->groupBy('id');
        })->take(10)->get();
```

Comment: Does `$product` have an `id` property?

Comment: Updated question because the code was misleading, i would like to get 10 or more products not a single product.

Comment: if you mean `$idOfModel` than no, eloquent doesn't works like that. you should define relations between `Product` -> `ProductOption` -> `Variable`

Comment: and what is the goal? to take products with options? or to grab options for products? or else

Comment: The goal is to take for each product their options with their variables/values, although i get what you are saying, i just hoped that there might be a solution to my thought.

Answer (score 0):

> The goal is to take for each product their options with their variables/values

so basically you just have to [define relations](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#main-content) correctly and eloquent will do everything for you (even [nested eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading))

```php
// Product model
// relations that fits your schema
public function attributes(){  
  return $this->relationName(Attribute::class); 
}

public function productOptions(){
  return $this->relationName(ProductOption::class);
}

//ProductOption model
public function vaiable(){
  return $this->relationName(Variable::class);
}

// then in controller
$products = Product::with(['attributes', productOptions.variable'])
  ->take(10)
  ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have access your `productId` using your first `Builder` like below.

```
$products = Product::with('attributes', function($q1) {
        $q1->with('product_options', function($q2) use ($q1) {
            $q2->where('product_id', $q1->id)->with('variable', function($q3) use ($q1) {
                $q3->where('product_id', $q1->id);
            });
        })->groupBy('id');
    })->take(10)->get();
```

Comment: After adding brackets and arrows to the with statements because i got an error for mb_strpos(), i get this error ```Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasManyThrough::$id```

Comment: So that might be because your relations has some problems. That's just the way that you access your `product_id`.